# Exportar encabezados DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

Mediante un datagridview genero un archivo TXT donde solo me arroja los resultados ¿Como exportar encabezados?

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\guest.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count -1 ; i++) 
            {
                writer.WriteLine("======================================================================================");
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.Write("\t" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
                }
                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine("======================================================================================");
            }
            writer.Close();
```

[image: Resultado Final]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener el valor asi

```
dataGridView2.Columns[j].HeaderText;
```